# Can't run MySQL code that seem to work for others

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

The goal of the code is to select Month, SaleID, Total and Growth. I can display Month, SaleID and Total but can't get Growth to work because it calculates from the the first row always. What am I doing wrong?

I've tried setting up variables, Emulating LAG(), PREV, CURRENT, NEXT to get the row the calculation should use but it won't register the native functions.

```
CREATE VIEW SalesTemp
    AS
        SELECT 
            DATE_FORMAT(Sales.SaleDate, "%Y-%m") AS Month,
            Sales.SaleID,
            Sales.Total
        FROM Sales
        WHERE SaleDate BETWEEN '2018-04-00' AND '2040-00-00' 
        GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(Sales.SaleDate, "%Y-%m"); 

SELECT * FROM SalesTemp;

DROP VIEW IF EXISTS PercentageGrowth;
CREATE VIEW PercentageGrowth 
    AS
        SELECT 
            DATE_FORMAT(Sales.SaleDate, "%Y-%m") AS Month,
            Sales.SaleID,
            Sales.Total,
            CONCAT(ROUND(((Sales.Total) - SalesTemp.Total) / (SELECT SalesTemp.Total FROM SalesTemp GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(SalesTemp.Month, "%Y-%m")) * 100, 2), "%") AS Growth
        FROM Sales, SalesTemp
        GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(Sales.SaleDate, "%Y-%m");

SELECT * FROM PercentageGrowth;

DROP VIEW PercentageGrowth;
DROP VIEW SalesTemp;
```

I want it to display growth of a company through the calculation of ((newValue - oldValue) / oldValue).

Since I can't link pictures I'll ascii what the result is. What I get from the SELECT now is:

```
+--------------------------------------+
|  Month  | SaleID |  Total  | Growth  |
| ------- | ------ | ------- | ------- |
| 2018-04 |    1   | 310.46  | 00.00%  |
| 2018-05 |    3   | 2160.62 | 595.54% |
| 2018-06 |    6   | 1087.89 | 250.21% |
| 2018-07 |    14  | 2314.54 | 645.09% |
+--------------------------------------+
```

I want it to say:

```
+--------------------------------------+
|  Month  | SaleID |  Total  | Growth  |
| ------- | ------ | ------- | ------- |
| 2018-04 |    1   | 310.46  | 00.00%  |
| 2018-05 |    3   | 2160.62 | 595.54% |
| 2018-06 |    6   | 1087.89 | -49.64% |
| 2018-07 |    14  | 2314.54 | 112.76% |
+--------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Why do you need to emulate? MySQL 8 now supports [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html) including `LAG`  and [CTEs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) to avoid the dropping and creating views.

Comment: Moreover, your aggregate queries does not group by *Sales.ID* which unfortunately is allowed in MySQL using the [ONLY FULL GROUP ON](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) mode turned off. Such a feature is an unfortunate disservice to new SQL users as such statements are invalid and would fail in *any* other database.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are cross joining your table pairings across all *SaleID* and all formatted date months and this is then further impacted by your unclear aggregations.

Assuming you use MySQL 8+, consider a couple of CTEs which includes `LAG` by one offset of your aggregated month totals:

```
WITH cte1 AS 
  (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Sales.SaleDate, "%Y-%m") AS `Month`,
          Sales.SaleID,
          SUM(Sales.Total) AS `Total_Sales`
   FROM Sales
   WHERE SaleDate BETWEEN '2018-04-00' AND '2040-00-00' 
   GROUP BY 
          DATE_FORMAT(Sales.SaleDate, "%Y-%m"),
          Sales.SaleID
  ),
    cte2 AS
  (SELECT *, 
          LAG(`Total_Sales`) OVER (PARTITION BY `SaleID` 
                                   ORDER BY `Month`) AS `Lag_Total_Sales`
   FROM cte1) 

SELECT `Month`, `SaleID`, `Total_Sales`,
       CONCAT(
              ROUND(
                    (`Total_Sales` - `Lag_Total_Sales`) / `Lag_Total_Sales` 
                    , 2) * 100
             , '%') AS `Growth`
FROM cte2
```

For MySQL 5.7 or less, consider a self-join of subquery that explicitly joins *SaleID* and any date in last month normalizing all dates to the first of their respective months.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(curr.FirstMonth, "%Y-%m") AS `Month`,
       curr.SaleID,
       curr.Total_Sales,
       CONCAT(
              ROUND((`curr`.Total_Sales - `prev`.Total_Sales) / `prev`.Total_Sales
                    , 2)*100  
             , '%') AS `Growth`
FROM
   (SELECT DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(SaleDate, INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
                    , INTERVAL 1 DAY) As FirstMonth,
           SaleID,
           SUM(`Total`) As `Total_Sales`
    FROM Sales
    GROUP BY 
           DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(SaleDate, INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
                    , INTERVAL 1 DAY),
           SaleID
   ) AS `curr`
LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(SaleDate, INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
                    , INTERVAL 1 DAY) As FirstMonth,
           SaleID,
           SUM(`Total`) As `Total_Sales`
    FROM Sales
    GROUP BY 
           DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(SaleDate, 
                                      INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) 
                    , INTERVAL 1 DAY),
           SaleID
   ) AS `prev`
ON `curr`.SaleID = `prev`.SaleID   
AND `curr`.FirstMonth - INTERVAL 1 MONTH = `prev`.FirstMonth
AND `curr`.FirstMonth BETWEEN '2018-04-00' AND '2040-00-00'
```

[Rextester Demo](https://rextester.com/ZOA57060) *(MySQL 5.7 version)*